# Incremental builds have been disabled with projects that include more than one third-party binding libraries

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I get this warning in Visual Studio when building an iOS project:

> Incremental builds have been disabled because this version of Xamarin.iOS does not support incremental builds on projects that include more than one third-party binding libraries. (MT0127)

How can I address this warning?

Answer (score 0):

In the solution, select the iOS project (double-click).
Go to **Build Settings** → **Code Generation and Runtime** → disable the **Incremental builds** checkbox for the offending configuration.

Alternatively, edit `...iOS.csproj` while the project is closed and remove all instances of

```
<MtouchFastDev>true</MtouchFastDev>
```

Clean all. Rebuild all.

Some references:

- [Incremental builds is disabled on GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/3174)
- [Xamarin.iOS errors at Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors)